# Why are SP security updates showing as Missing/Required?

Tags: 2010, security, update, patching, psconfig

Let me preface by saying, I already ran the `Get-SPProduct -local` but I think it's because the security updates are not there. I have a couple questions regarding security updates and patching as this is not a subject that I could find the answer to online.

We have a security update (KB3191840) Version 14.0.7180.5001 that its status is "Missing/Required", and what I've found is that it may have been updated through our WSUS servers automatically.

1. Why is this security update showing for **ALL** servers? How does it know it's required? Does it look at the OS security fixes, such as rollups that have nothing to do with SharePoint to determine that and if so, why does it know the version?
2. What risks do I have to just use the `-installcheck noinstallcheck` switch on PSConfig? Since it upgrades everything successfully thereafter.